# Pathname matching and listing program

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-system, unix, portability

This Python 3 program outputs a list of all pathnames in the filesystem
that match a list of rules taken from a file. You can add and remove
sets of pathnames.

The original purpose was to generate lists of pathnames to feed to
`cpio` for backups. A simplified version of one of my backup rulefiles
should clarify how it works:

```bash
# Entire home directory
+ /home/tom
# Remove hidden files and other junk
- /home/tom/.*
- /home/tom/java
# Then add back stuff that I do want
+ /home/tom/.bash*
# Remove stuff that goes in another backup
- /home/tom/inactive
# Add stuff from another location
+ /large/bkups/patterns
# Remove junk
- *~
- *.o
```

This would produce output such as:

```
/home/tom
/home/tom/.bashrc
/home/tom/bin
/home/tom/bin/fpmr
/large/bkups/patterns
/large/bkups/patterns/current
/large/bkups/patterns/inactive
```

`fpmr -h` gives a short help text. `fpmr -?` would normally give a long
help text, but since it's quite long and the contents don't affect the
code, I removed it from the code posted below. I'll keep it available
here for a while:

<s>http://tomzy.ch/code/fpmr_detailed_help.txt</s> (this is now a dead link)

Aside from general code review, I'm particularly interested in the
following:

- I use a couple of global flags. It seemed the best way. Thoughts?
- Can anyone think of cases I've overlooked?
- Does any code seem to need more comments? I find most Python code
  clear enough to be self-documenting.
- It was developed on Linux. Is there anything that wouldn't work right
  on other Unices?
- It lists regular files, directories, and symlinks. It ignores named
  pipes, sockets, and device files. A Solaris filesystem can contain
  something called a "door". Can any Solaris users verify that it will
  ignore doors too?

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import sys

try:
    import argparse
except ImportError:
    print('The "argparse" module is not available. '
          'Use Python 3.2 or better.', file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

import fnmatch
import glob
import os
import os.path as osp
import re


detailed_help = """
Omitted for brevity. Will be available here for a while:
http://tomzy.ch/code/fpmr_detailed_help.txt
""".strip()


# Global flags. Usually bad practice, but I think justified in this
# instance. Values are set once in main(), based on args, and are
# constant thereafter; they are read deep in call trees and would be too
# inconvenient to pass around.

GLOBAL_verbose = None
GLOBAL_null = None


def main():
    args = process_args()
    global GLOBAL_verbose
    GLOBAL_verbose = args.verbose
    global GLOBAL_null
    GLOBAL_null = args.null

    rule_list = read_rules(args.rulefile)
    if not rule_list:
        error_quit('No valid rules')

    vmsg('{} valid rules'.format(len(rule_list)))

    dirs = set()
    nondirs = set()

    for action, pattern in rule_list:
        vmsg('=====\nApplying rule {} {}'
                    ''.format(action, pattern))
        if action == '+':
            add_matches(dirs, nondirs, pattern)
        else:
            remove_matches(dirs, nondirs, pattern)

    report_descend_failures(dirs)

    paths = dirs | nondirs
    if not paths:
        error_quit('No matches were found')

    if len(paths) != len(dirs) + len(nondirs):
        error_quit(
            'Something weird happened. The following pathnames\n'
            'are listed as both directories and non-directories:\n'
            '  {}'.format('\n  '.join(sorted(dirs & nondirs))))

    line_end = '\0' if args.null else '\n'
    plist = [p + line_end for p in paths]
    if args.relative:
        plist = [p.lstrip(os.sep) for p in plist]
    plist.sort()
    args.outfile.writelines(plist)


def process_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='fpmr: Find Pathnames that Match Rules',
        epilog='For more information, run "fpmr -?".')

    parser.add_argument(
        'rulefile', type=argparse.FileType('r'),
        help='rule file (use "-" to read from stdin)')

    parser.add_argument(
        '-?', '--details', action=detail_action,
        nargs=0, default=argparse.SUPPRESS,
        help='show more detailed help')

    parser.add_argument(
        '-r', '--relative', action='store_true',
        help='output relative pathnames (default is absolute)')

    parser.add_argument(
        '-0', '--null', action='store_true',
        help='end pathnames with null character (default is newline)')

    parser.add_argument(
        '-v', '--verbose', action='store_true',
        help='print extended debug info to stderr')

    parser.add_argument(
        '-o', action='store', dest='outfile', default='-',
        type=argparse.FileType('w'),
        help='write output to outfile (default is stdout)',
        metavar='outfile')

    return parser.parse_args()


class detail_action(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, p, n, v, o=None):
        print(detailed_help)
        sys.exit(0)


def read_rules(rulefile):
    # Return list of valid rules.

    rlist = []
    for lineno, line in enumerate(rulefile, 1):
        line = line.strip()
        if not line or line[:1] == '#':
            continue

        rule = parse_rule(line, lineno)
        if rule:
            rlist.append(rule)
            vmsg('Rule added from line {}: {} {}'
                 ''.format(lineno, rule[0], rule[1]))

    return rlist


def parse_rule(line, lineno):
    # Return a valid rule as a tuple. Issue a warning for an invalid
    # rule and return None.

    try:
        mobj = re.match(r'([+-])\s*(.*)', line)
        if not mobj:
            raise ValueError
        action, pattern = mobj.groups()
        if not pattern:
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        warn('Malformed rule ignored at line {}'.format(lineno))
        return None

    if action == '+' and not osp.isabs(pattern):
        warn('Invalid rule ignored at line {}\n'
              '  (additive rule with relative pathname)'
              ''.format(lineno))
        return None

    if pattern[-1:] == os.sep:
        pattern = pattern.rstrip(os.sep)
        warn('Trailing slashes removed from rule at line {}'
             ''.format(lineno))

    return action, pattern


def add_matches(dirs, nondirs, pattern):
    for path in glob.iglob(pattern):
        if is_true_dir(path):
            add_path(dirs, 'dirs', path)
            add_tree(dirs, nondirs, path)
        else:
            add_path(nondirs, 'nondirs', path)


def add_tree(dirs, nondirs, top):
    vmsg('<<< {} paths before walking {}'
         ''.format(len(dirs) + len(nondirs), top))

    for wpath, wdirs, wfiles in os.walk(top, onerror=walk_error):
        vmsg('<< {} paths before adding contents of {}'
             ''.format(len(dirs) + len(nondirs), wpath))

        # wdirs includes links to true dirs.
        for d in wdirs:
            fullpath = osp.join(wpath, d)
            if is_true_dir(fullpath):
                add_path(dirs, 'dirs', fullpath)
            else:
                add_path(nondirs, 'nondirs', fullpath)

        for f in wfiles:
            add_path(nondirs, 'nondirs', osp.join(wpath, f))

        vmsg('>> {} paths after adding contents of {}'
             ''.format(len(dirs) + len(nondirs), wpath))

    vmsg('>>> {} paths after walking {}'
         ''.format(len(dirs) + len(nondirs), top))


def is_true_dir(path):
    return osp.isdir(path) and not osp.islink(path)


def add_path(pset, setname, path):
    # Add only files, directories, and links.
    # Must check islink() to include broken links.

    if osp.isfile(path) or osp.isdir(path) or osp.islink(path):
        size = len(pset)
        pset.add(path)
        if '\n' in path and not GLOBAL_null:
            warn('Pathname contains a newline; '
                 'consider using -0\n  {!r}'.format(path))

        if GLOBAL_verbose:
            if len(pset) > size:
                vmsg('Added to {}: {}'.format(setname, path))
            else:
                vmsg('Not added to {} because already there: {}'
                     ''.format(setname, path))
    else:
        vmsg('Not added due to file type: {}'.format(path))


def remove_matches(dirs, nondirs, pattern):
    vmsg('<<< {} paths before removing pattern {}'
         ''.format(len(dirs) + len(nondirs), pattern))

    # Special rule: if pattern is a directory, remove it and change
    # pattern to dir/* so subsequent code will remove all contents.
    if pattern in dirs:
        dirs.remove(pattern)
        pattern += os.sep + '*'

    for setname, pset in ('dirs', dirs), ('nondirs', nondirs):
        to_remove = set(fnmatch.filter(pset, pattern))
        if GLOBAL_verbose:
            for p in sorted(to_remove):
                vmsg('Removing from {}: {}'.format(setname, p))
        pset -= to_remove

    vmsg('>>> {} paths after removing pattern {}'
         ''.format(len(dirs) + len(nondirs), pattern))


def report_descend_failures(dirs):
    # Try to descend into all directories, and report failures.
    # os.walk() will have reported non-readable ones, but not those that
    # are readable and not searchable.

    saved_cwd = os.getcwd()

    for d in dirs:
        try:
            os.chdir(d)
        except:
            warn('{} could not be entered; mode {}'
                 ''.format(d, oct(os.stat(d).st_mode)[-3:]))

    os.chdir(saved_cwd)


def walk_error(err):
    warn('{}: {}'.format(err.filename, err.strerror))


def vmsg(msg):
    if GLOBAL_verbose:
        print(msg, file=sys.stderr)


def warn(msg):
    errwarn(msg, 'Warning')


def error_quit(msg):
    errwarn(msg, 'Error')
    sys.exit(1)


def errwarn(msg, prefix):
    progname = osp.basename(sys.argv[0])
    print('{}: {}: {}'.format(progname, prefix, msg), file=sys.stderr)


main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some comments:

- Please use docstrings.
- Note that `argparse` can be installed from [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse) for older python versions.
- For the computation of relative paths, please have a look at `os.path.relpath`.
- I don't like using global flags either. What about using a class to store that internal state?
- Instead of `vmsg`, `errwarn`, etc., please use the `logging` module (`logging.error`, `logging.warning`, etc.).
- `GLOBAL_verbose` could be replaced also using `logging.debug` and setting log level based on the command line argument.
- Instead of calling `main` at the bottom of the script directly, please use the usual convention:

  ```
  if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
  ```
- Try to parse arguments before calling main and pass them to main. This way, it will be testable if you want to write test cases in the future:

  ```
  if __name__ == '__main__':
      args = process_args()
      main(args)
  ```
- `line[:1] == '#'` could be reduced to `line[0] == '#'`, but I find more readable this:  `line.startswith('#')`
- `pattern[-1:] == os.sep` could be reduced to `pattern[-1] == os.sep`, but I find more readable this: `pattern.endswith(os.sep)`

I hope this helps.

Edit: Regarding using a `class` instead of globals, what I meant more or less is following this pattern:

```
class Script(object):

    """Docstring."""

    def __init__(self, verbose, null):
        """Docstring."""
        self.verbose = verbose
        self.null = null

    ...
    def run(self):
        """Docstring."""
        <put here the code in the original main function>

    ...

    def add_path(self, pset, setname, path):
        """Docstring."""
        ...
        if '\n' in path and not self.null:
            ...
        if self.verbose:
            ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = process_args()
    script = Script(args.verbose, args.null)
    script.run()
```

Of course this is just a starting point. After some work in the script you might want to create a `Rule` class or a `RuleProcessor` class.

Comment: Lots of good suggestions here, thank you! I hadn't noticed `logging`, will check it out. For the class replacing the globals, do you mean I should pass an object around, or do you mean I should make a global object that is created in `main()`? Or something else?

Comment: Added an example to the response about how I'd start using a class to store internal state and get rid of globals.

Comment: Um. Not sure about that idea. If we only put the parts that use the flags into the class, it looks complicated. If we put everything into the class, then aren't we just replacing module globals with class globals? I don't see what we gain.

Comment: As I said, that's the starting point to refactor the code into a more object oriented approach. Anyway, if you are happy with the way it is right now, there's no reason to change it.